# linking glew32.dll in my program shows an error as missing when in System32 file despite that its there

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, dll

I created glew32.dll from source using the source code from the website and running these commands

```
gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude  -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c
gcc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a    -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -nostdlib
ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o
```

i moved the subsequent files to the correct locations i.e libglew32.dll libglew32.dll.a and the include files tot he include files of mingw include/GL etc

i use ming32 gcc to compile my programs , and when i run the commands gcc .... -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 etc its compiles fine

but however when i run the program with opengl32.dll in Windows/System32 i get the error that glew32.dll doesnt exist

but when i move the glew32.dll file to the mingw32 bin folder it runs fine

what seems to be the issue since i have actually the glew32.dll file to Windows/System32 and the system doesnt seem to be able to find it

when i run "where glew32.dll" it shows both locations correctly, but somehow the linker is not picking it up

System32 is in environmental path "%SystemRoot%\System32..." but yet the error comes up when i try to run it with opengl32.dll in System32 file while being out of mingw32/bin file

Comment: This might be a 32/64-bit issue. If you're looking in `C:\windows\system32` and running on Windows 64-bit, make sure your program is 64-bit. If your program is 32-bit, you need `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Comment: your spot on right, that solved the problem